# VirtualBox: cursor invisible in some part of the screen

Tags: macos, virtualbox, mouse

I'm running an OSX guest (High Sierra) inside VirtualBox (6.0.2 r128162). I have installed the guest additions, and the extension pack. I have enabled 3D acceleration, and gave 128MB of video memory to the guest.

I have an UHD screen, and when using the UHD resolution (3840*2160) on the guest, there's a part of the screen where the mouse cursor is hidden. I can click, but I can't see the cursor.

This area is a vertical column covering the screen from the top to the bottom, starting at something like 2/3 from the left of the screen to something like 4/5.

I can't disable the mouse capture (the option is disabled).

I also have Ubuntu and Windows guests working fine on the same computer.

Does someone knows how to fix this?

Thanks

EDIT: another problem today: when displaying the VM in fullscreen on an external monitor, it is displayed in the bottom right corner (so the top left corner of the VM is roughly at the middle of the external monitor).

Comment: @tim-autim: any follow up on this issue? I'm facing the same!

Comment: No sorry, I had to gave up.

Comment: @tim-autim: I'm trying using KVM and the performance is better (at least no display/mouse weird issues. Take a look: https://github.com/kholia/OSX-KVM

Answer (score 3):

If you are using only a trackpad, this is sometimes fixed by changing your pointing device from **PS/2 Mouse** to **USB Tablet**.

Steps to follow:

1. Ensure the Guest in not currently running
2. In VirtualBox, highlight the affected virtual-guest in the list of guests on the left.
3. Select **Settings**
4. Select **System** on the left column
5. On **Motherboard** tab, change your Pointing Device from **PS/2 Mouse** to **USB Tablet**. It sounds odd, but it worked for both my Macbook Pro and an IBM Lenovo for CentOS 7 guest.

Note that there used to be a VirtualBox bug a few years ago with 3D Acceleration being enabled on Macs. You might also try temporarily disabling that as a test if the above doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried all of these without success. When using PS/2, I have no cursor at all, when using the other modes I have the problem I described. Disabling 3D acceleration has no effect.